# Is it possible to get Wordpress working in a ASP.NET MVC 3 running Azure?

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc-3, wordpress, azure

I'm looking to provide blog functionalites into my website for our users. I know that it's possible to get Wordpress working in Azure. We are using ASP.NET MVC 3 in Azure. Is it possible to get wordpress running inside a ASP.NET MVC 3 Azure application? If yes, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> WordPress is a content management system (CMS) based on PHP and MySQL.

See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress)

> The ASP.NET MVC Framework is a web application framework that implements the model-view-controller (MVC) pattern. Based on ASP.NET.

See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework)

ASP.NET MVC is what you can USE to build a website/cms etc, **but** wordpress was built with a different language and technology (PHP)

I would recommend orchard : http://orchardproject.net/  ( http://orchard.codeplex.com)

It's **built** with asp.net mvc and supports running on Azure.

---

If you need to RUN Php on windows azure you can, see this : http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/

[See how to setup windows azure for PHP](http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/setup-the-windows-azure-sdk-for-php)

Comment: I have looked at Orchard but it doesn't have anywhere near the features and community that Wordpress has. I'm trying to see if it's possible to have a php app run inside of ASP.NET.

I have found this but not sure if it will work.
[asp-net-and-php-on-iis-together](http://www.joshholmes.com/blog/2010/11/11/asp-net-and-php-on-iis-together/)

Comment: @Hoang I updated my answer, that link you have on your comment is about running ASP.NET and PHP _(which are two languages)_ on the same server, you can't run one language INSIDE another _(asp.net inside php, doesn't make sense)_ Yes, you can run php _(a language)_ on Windows Azure. I've added links describing those in my answer.

Comment: From the link I provided, it mentions that you can run php inside of a folder in asp.net so there might be a possibility.

Comment: I just found this http://www.php-compiler.net/blog/2012/wordpress-on-dotnet-with-sql-server-using-phalanger-3-0

Comment: @Hoang both your first link and this talk about running php inside IIS, along with asp.net, the second talks about running a precompiled wordpress install, inside an IIS virtual directory (or sub directory)  so there is no need to install PHP